# Generate series count on multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following queries which counts how many `doctor_profiles` records were created by week

```
SELECT w.week, COUNT(doctor_profiles.*) AS total
FROM (SELECT generate_series(min(DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at)),
                             max(DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at)),
                             interval '7 day'
                            ) as week
      FROM doctor_profiles
     ) w LEFT JOIN
     "doctor_profiles" 
     ON DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at) = w.week
GROUP BY w.week
ORDER BY w.week;
```

I also have a column `approved` that I'd like to add a sum count for each week. I tried adding `COUNT(doctor_profiles.approved) as approved` (boolean field) but the count returns the same number as `doctor_profiles`. How can I query for a sum of all `doctor_profiles` that were approved until the end of that time period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT w.week, COUNT(*) AS total, SUM(approved::int) as approved
FROM (SELECT generate_series(min(DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at)),
                             max(DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at)),
                             interval '7 day'
                            ) as week
      FROM doctor_profiles
     ) w LEFT JOIN
     "doctor_profiles" dp
     ON DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at) = w.week
GROUP BY w.week
ORDER BY w.week;
```